# Even if you start Rails in Sakura Cloud, it will be "Can not access this site"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am planning to use the Sakura Cloud to perform the production operation of Rails application.
I constructed the environment according to the following procedure and started the server, but it was useless.

**Flow of environment construction**

1. I set Sakura Cloud as below and did an ssh log in from the development environment.
2. I installed Ruby using Rbenv, and installed bundler, and Rails.
3. I started the server with `RAILS_ENV = production bundle exec rails s - e production - b <IPv4 address>`.

It is my first time to use production and Sakura Cloud, so it may be that I have missed or made a mistake with some setting.
It will be helpful if someone with detailed knowledge lets me know.

**Setting of Sakura Cloud**

- 1 core, 1 GB
- CentOS 7.5

NIC is Internet connection, paravirtualized mode (I do not understand this in any way.)
The public key contains the public key generated in the development environment, there is no startup script

**Application stacks**

- ruby 2.2.10
- rails 5.0.7
- puma
  SQLite 3

Comment: @MarekLipka Nope, you are wrong. It is not in Chinese.

Comment: Google Translate perfromed pretty well here, I guess

Comment: @PavelOganesyan I was impressed and was just about to praise you for having done a good translation in such a short time, before you wrote the comment above. However, it has some small mistranslations.

Comment: @rrr323 英語以外の言語で質問すると、このように弾かれることが多いです。今回は親切な人が英語に書き換えてくれたので良かったですが、答えは英語で返ってきます。日本語で質問したいなら https://ja.stackoverflow.com/ にするとよいでしょう。